# submit multiple unique forms with ajax on one page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So, I have this schedule, selfcreated with HTML tables and Mysql Database inputs.
It looks something like this:

Week -- Monday -- Thuesday -- Wednesday -- Thursday -- Friday -- Saturday -- Sunday

And for example, in **week 5 on Thuesday** there is me working, **Stan 12:00 - 19:00.**

I want to add another employee on this day and I do not want to refresh the page so I tried to do it with ajax.
So I click the button that adds an employee, I now need to see a little form with a option box for all employee names, and another input for the time.
After I click add I need it to add the employees name to the schedule with the time and it has to be saved into the database.

This is how the schedule looks like:
[image]

There are 2 times a plus button. The second plus button is the button I try to add, it will not redirect me to another page but just toggles an division.
So whenever I click on the second plus button I have this:
[image]

Now I can easily select an employee and give them a time to work.
But now here is my problem. If I add them I want it to add the employee to the database that will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rooster (idusers,week, thuesday) VALUES ('1','8','12:00 - 16:00');
```

And it needs to add the employees name and time to the day just like the other names (you see in the pictures).

So, **plus button --> show division where you can add an employee --> add employee to database and show the name and time like the other names on the page.**

Right now when I add someone it will only show me some text and because I've used the result class division in each table row it will automaticly update it in each row which is not my intension.

The text only needs to appear on the day I added someone.
Follow these steps:
[image]
[image]

Here is my code I use:
For the plus button (second one):

```
echo ' <a class="first" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
       <form method="POST" id="reg-form" style="display:none;">
     <div id="form" class="result">


      <select name="gebruikersnaam" class="design">';
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($all_u)) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$row['gebruikersnaam']."'>".$row['gebruikersnaam']."</option>";
                                        }
                                    echo '</select>

        <br/><input type="text" value="00:00 - 24:00" name="test"/>      
        <button type="submit">+</button>


      </div>
      </form>   
';
```

For the ajax handling:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function()
 {

  //var fn = $("#fname").val();
  //var ln = $("#lname").val();

  //var data = 'fname='+fn+'&lname='+ln;

  var data = $(this).serialize();


  $.ajax({

  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'submit.php',
  data : data,
  success :  function(data)
       {
      $("#reg-form").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
      {
       $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function()
       {
        $(".result").html(data);
       });
      });

       }
  });
  return false;
 });
```

And the submit.php (for the ajax)

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phno = $_POST['phno'];

 ?>

    <table border="0">

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Succedd !!!</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $fname ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $lname ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Your eMail</td>
    <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Contact No</td>
    <td><?php echo $phno; ?></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <?php

}

?>
```

If you need any more information, PLEASE ASK!
If you want to look closer, please send me a PM I will give you a test account.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: If forms are unique - why do they have the same id `reg-form`?

Comment: @u_mulder thats my question, how to create unique forms for each row in the table.

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird Just change the `id` of the forms?

Comment: use class instead of ID...then you have `this` in form to reference any other elements to update in a traverse

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have a html table, in each row of that table I need this unique form so I can easily add people. Something I have to do is like when I click on the plus button It has to open a ajax form for that specific day, week and year. Somewhere I need to store that data?

Comment: @charlietfl that is actually a good idea. But I do not know how to combine that with my situation.

Comment: get rid of all the pictures in question and provide a better sample of raw html ( not php). You can always traverse up to `closest('td')` as main reference point to then use `find()` and all instances will be isolated. Not really sure exactly how html is structured but those 2 methods are the simplest instance isolation methods for repeating componennts

Answer (score 1):

If you have several forms - either use distinct `ids` for them or simply - use `class`:

```
<form method="POST" class="reg-form" style="display:none;">
    <div id="form" class="result"> // and remove this id too
```

Js handler:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reg-form', function()  // class reg-form
{
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // here you use $(this). Do you know what is it? It'a jquery object of your submitted form

    // we need `this$` variable because in a functions `this` 
    // refers to some different objects, not submitted form
    var this$ = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'submit.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
        {
            // now you want to fade out only the submitted form
            // but the submitted form is this$
            this$.fadeOut(500).hide(function()
            {
                // and you want to show only one .result
                // which is inside your submitted form - use .find
                this$.find(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                {
                    // same here
                    this$.find(".result").html(data);
                });
            });

        }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: You should rebuild your form as `div.result` is inside a `form`, so when a `form` `fadesOut` - `.result` is `fadingIn` but you don't see it, as parent form is not visible. Or you don't even need to `fadeout` `form` but just replace it's content with new `data`.

Comment: I understand. How to replace the content instead of fading in and out?

Comment: Thanks it worked! 
But now, I want to add more than one employee in order. So I add one, and I click + and after that I want to add that day one more. How to do that :S?

Comment: is there any way to sum up the texts? Like when I click the + button it will show the name for example: Stan. And after I click the button another time there will come Stan again. So the output will be Stan Stan instead of replacing the previous Stan.